# Checkboxes and Radio buttons binded to same Booleans. WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have two radio buttons and two checkboxes. Depending on the bool, they are visible only on radio buttons or checkboxes. The first checkbox and radio button are bind to bool IsEcological, and the second checkbox and radio button are bind to bool IsNonEcological. When radio buttons aren't visible (only checkboxes are visible), I can only check one checkbox, and can't select both. What can I do to be able to select two checkboxes?

I was thinking about making separate bools to radio buttons and checkboxes, but this doesn't seem as best/optimal way, I also tried setting IsEnabled="false" to radio buttons when they are invisible, but that didn't work.

```
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding IsFarmEcological, Converter={StaticResource EnumToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter='Entirely'}" 
            Orientation="Horizontal" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <RadioButton
        Margin="10"
        Content="Eco"
        IsChecked="{Binding IsEcological, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <RadioButton
        Margin="10"
        Content="Non Eco"
        IsChecked="{Binding IsNonEcological, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding IsFarmEcological, Converter={StaticResource EnumToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter='Partially'}" 
            Orientation="Horizontal" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <CheckBox
        Margin="10"
        Content="Eco"
        IsChecked="{Binding IsEcological, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <CheckBox
        Margin="10"
        Content="Non Eco"
        IsChecked="{Binding IsNonEcological, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Is IsFarmEcological is enum? If so, it does not match your description. Having both IsEcological and IsNonEcological seems redundant. What is your scenario?

Comment: @emoacht IsFarmEcological is an enum and applies to the whole thing. IsEcological and IsNonEcological apply only to part of the farm (like food production), it's one of a few cases - I have more stack panels for different production types.

Comment: In your code, the visibilities of RadioButtons and CheckBoxes depend on IsFarmEcological and _Depending on the bool_ indicates it is bool. Then, IsEcological and IsNonEcological naturally indicate the opposite values and it doesn't make sense to having the two properties for one attribute. In addition, you didn't explain why the two CheckBoxes cannot be checked at the same time. In the first place, why do you need two CheckBoxes for one attribute?

Comment: Please think about why both states of a binary value should ever be true? Why can IsRed and IsNotRed both true when both states are the inversion of each other? For example *TRUE = NOT FALSE* and *FALSE = NOT TRUE* but *TRUE ≠ FALSE*. That's the fundamental basics of boolean algebra. Sounds like you suffer from a serious flawed understanding of logic.

Comment: However, RadioButtons of a common group are always mutual exclusive. While the hidden/collapsed RadioButtons are not visible, their binding is still attached. They will force mutual exclusiveness on their source values because they are designed top maintain a mutual exclusive group state. Simply don't bind check boxes and radio buttons of a common group to the same data. If you need more help, please explain what you are trying to achieve. It seems you just posted a really bad example.